# Yield in Python3

Tags: yield

'y' is the yield function. 'ls (num)' creates a list. Variables 'q' and 'c' to keep track of how the 'y' function works. I expect 'y' to slice the lists produced by the 'ls' function according to the indices of the list 't'. But for some reason 'y' at each iteration adds a new value to the list 't' but does not increase the value of 'q'. This behavior of the yield function is not clear to me. Please explain why this is happening.

```
t=[1,3,5]

def ls(num):
    if num==1:
        return [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    elif num==2:
        return [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
    elif num==3:
        return [21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29]

def y(t, num=1, all=True):
    q=0
    print('t {}'.format(t))
    lst=ls(num)
    c=0
    if all==True:
        t.append(len(lst))
        print('t in if',t)
        q+=1
        print('q ',q)
    for j in t:
        c+=1
        print('c {}'.format(c))
        yield lst[:j]
            
for i in range(3):
    print('round {}'.format(i))
    for v in range(1,4):
        for l in y(t,num=v):
            print(l)




[enter image description here][1]
[enter image description here][2]
[enter image description here][3]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have defined the `t` variable in the outer scope, but `q` is defined inside the scope of the `y` function. When you modify `t` inside `y`, it is also modified outside `y`. `q` however is re-defined every time `y` is called.

There are many solutions. Here are two:

1. make a copy of t by adding `t = copy.copy(t)` inside `y`
2. change `t.append(length)` to `t = t + [length]`

Comment: Thanks. for some reason, I thought that the yield function, starting from the second iteration, skips part of the code before the loop and starts executing only what is inside the loop. I was probably wrong)

Comment: @KortezKortez in the loop `for l in y(t): ...;` that would be correct, however the full y-function is executed again each time `for v in range(1,4):...;` is iterating.

Comment: Thanks. As they say in Russia: "live forever, learn forever")